# Add an array of string to ProjectionOperation in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I need to add the fields(get from ui) which need to be fetched using mongodb Aggregation,

From uri i will get param as fields which has comma seperated string of fields

```
http://foo.com?fields=id,name
```

A document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "3a237c007a87d", 
    "name" : "Available", 
    "is_active" : true, 
 }
```

The below will work as i want and produce the result

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(            
            project(fields.contains("name") ? "name" : "",
                    fields.contains("id") ? "id" : ""),
                    fields.contains("is_active") ? "is_active" : ""),
            skip((page-1)*limit),
            limit(limit)
            );
```

The above query gets what i want and its shown belo

```
{
    "_id" : "3a237c007a87d", 
    "name" : "Available"
 }
```

IF i run with below query i m getting **atleast one field need to specify in project**
And the code:

```
ProjectionOperation project = project();
for(String field : fields) {
    project.andInclude(field);
}
```

but the field is not adding in projectionOperation
if projectOperation need to like to have

```
{ "$project" : {"id":1, "name":1 } }

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(            
        project,
        skip((page-1)*limit),
        limit(limit)
        );

 The output need to be

{
    "_id" : "3a237c007a87d", 
    "name" : "Available"
 }
```

I like to avoid check whether the list contain the field as they want in project.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're just confusing some variables here (`fields` vs `fieldList`)? Also, you need to use the return value of the `andInclude()` call Try this instead:

```
List<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();
fieldList.add("id");
fieldList.add("name");
ProjectionOperation project = project();
for(String field : fieldList) { // note that I'm using 'fieldList' here
    project = project.andInclude(field);
}
```